# i want a simple query to calculate fine of books in a library management system

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a grid view at my front end aspx page.
I want to show fines of each issued book. If there is no fine it show "Zero" on that row.

```
DECLARE @Days INT,
        @IssueDate DATE = (SELECT IssueDate FROM ISSUEBOOKSTUDENT),
        @ReturnDate DATE = (SELECT ReturnDate FROM ISSUEBOOKSTUDENT)

SET @Days = DATEDIFF(d,@IssueDate,@ReturnDate)

SELECT 
    (CASE
        WHEN @Days < 2 
           THEN @Days * 10 
           ELSE 0 
     END) Fine
```

I have tried the above query, but it is causing errors.

Comment: Please edit your post adding Tables structure and the error. Why do you set "asp.net" tag?

Comment: What error you are receiving ?

Comment: Not sure you are receiving error about `Subquery returned more than 1 value`. If so you can use this query `SELECT *, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, IssueDate, ReturnDate) < 2 THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, IssueDate, ReturnDate) * 10 ELSE 0 END AS Fine
FROM IssueBookStudent`

Comment: Thanks sir, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Think the approach you are using is wrong. for getting the issued date and return date you are not passing any book identified.

try using below query

```
SELECT 
case when DATEDIFF(d,IssueDate ,ReturnDate ) > 2 then (DATEDIFF(d,IssueDate ,ReturnDate )) *10 else 0 end AS FINE
     from ISSUEBOOKSTUDENT
```